# Split a string with ',' and with conditions

Tags: java

Split a string with token `,`. The preconditions are:

- it should remove the spaces after the comma i.e. `x,----y -> [x,y]`
- it should remove the spaces before the comma i.e. `x----,y -> [x,y]`
- it should remove the spaces after the last value i.e. `x,y---- -> [x,y]`
- it should remove the spaces before the first value i.e. `-----x,y -> [x,y]`

I tried with `Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*")).split("x,y"))`
But it could not resolve the 3 and 4th preconditions.

**N.B. spaces are designated as -**

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve so we can see what you're doing wrong. Myself, I'd trim the String and then surround the comma with white space identifier `\s*,\s*`.

Comment: `Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*")).split("x,y".trim()))`

Comment: Is this a Guava splitter? If it is, `Splitter.on(',').trimResults()` should do it. Also, `Splitter.splitToList` might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a Guava `Splitter`, so you can use:

```
Splitter.on(',').trimResults().splitToList(string)
```

If you're not using that, you can just manually trim the fragments after splitting:

```
String[] frags = string.split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < frags.length; ++i) {
  frags[i] = frags[i].trim();
}
return Lists.newArrayList(frags);
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
Lists.newArrayList(string.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Comment: nice solution on guava.